# The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to read in cifar10 dataset and use it for training a model , so I try to read batches and run the session as below:

```
 # Optimizer
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0001)
    global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', initializer=tf.constant(0), trainable=False)
    train_op = opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, var_list), global_step=global_step)

    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([x_train, y_train], batch_size=batch_size)
    #image_batch_uint8 = tf.cast(image_batch, tf.uint8)

    # Train
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(10000000):
            _loss_value, _reward_value, _ = sess.run([loss, reward, train_op], feed_dict={
                images_ph: image_batch,
                labels_ph: label_batch
            })
            if i % 100 == 0:
                print('iter: ', i, '\tloss: ', _loss_value, '\treward: ', _reward_value)
```

However I get this error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1086, in _run
    'feed with key ' + str(feed) + '.')
The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.For reference, the tensor object was Tensor("batch:0", shape=(32, 50000, 32, 32, 3), dtype=uint8) which was passed to the feed with key Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 1024), dtype=float32).
```

What am I doing wrong? I am not sure what the error is about.

Comment: `image_batch` and `label_batch` are tf.tensors (not numpy arrays). You can only feed numpy arrays / lists when feeding data using `feed_dict`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using tf.train.batch however, I will always get tensors then and I don't see a straightforward way to convert them to numpy arrays. What would you advise me?

Comment: It seems I will need to run a session? Is there a better way to get batches then I wonder

Comment: If you look at [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/batch) it's going to be deprecated. So I suggest you use, `tf.data`.